# .join(',') on Array results in strange results when saving to file

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, csv

I need to do simple file manipulation. Get data from one txt file and save it in csv format. My regex is getting all the data and saving it in the array, but when I try to join array elements and post it in the file it does something strange.

When debugging variable `the_line` and printing it via `puts the_line` this is the result

```
AN.A-1437/2014 z dnia 2014.04.03
3706
DEZ 1380/2014
Obrót
Wolny rynek
Osoba fizyczna
Osoba fizyczna
334 650.00 zł   
niezabudowana  przeznaczona pod zabudowę inną niż 
WA1L/00022800/1
8 - RAJSZEW
42/2014
9/18
2231 ( LzVI 1402 RVI 829)
```

but when I run `out_file.puts(the_line.join(','))` the resulting file looks like this

```
AN.A-1437/2014 z dnia 2014.04.03
,3706
,DEZ 1380/2014
,Obrót
,Wolny rynek
,Osoba fizyczna
,Osoba fizyczna
,334 650.00 zł
,niezabudowana  przeznaczona pod zabudowę inną niż 
,WA1L/00022800/1
,8 - RAJSZEW
,42/2014
,9/18
,2231 ( LzVI 1402 RVI 829)
,Tereny zabudowy usługowej
,Własność
,1/1
```

Which is very strange for me. When I run `test.rb` and manually create the array and save it to the file it works fine. So I guess it's something with how I create the array. But what?
Here is the full code:

```
out_file = File.open('files/out.csv', 'w')
in_file = File.open('files/in.txt')

first_plot = true
the_line = []
n = 0
in_file.each do |line| 
  n += 1
  #the ===== line suggests it's time to save the line and start filling the second one. This is were I have problems somehow
  if line =~ /=+/
    out_file.puts(the_line.join(','))
    the_line = []
    first_plot = true
  #This is because every transaction can have several plots and I have to start new line as well. I know this needs refractoring. 
  elsif line=~ /Numer/
    if !(first_plot)
      if line =~ /:\d+\/*\d*$/
        out_file.puts the_line.join(',')
        13.times { |i| the_line << '' }
      elsif line=~/:\d+\/*\d*;\d+$/
        out_file.puts the_line.join(',')
        19.times { |i| the_line << ''}
      elsif line=~/:\d+\/*\d*;\d+,\d+$/
        out_file.puts the_line.join(',')
        30.times { |i| the_line << ''}
      end
    else 
      #this is the first time the plot is seen so we can have it in one line with transaction details
      first_plot = false
      m = /:(\S.*)$/.match(line)
      the_line << $1
    end
  #This is for every normal value
  elsif line=~/:(\S.*)$/
    the_line << $1
  else
    if line =~ /[a-zA-Z]+ :\s+$/
    else
      puts "#{n}: Error: #{line}"
    end
  end
end
out_file.close
in_file.close
```

And this is sample file I need to manipulate (I want to extract values after : basicly)

```
Dokument             :AN.A-1437/2014 z dnia 2014.04.03
IRCW                 :3706
Opis                 :DEZ 1380/2014
Rodzaj zapisu        :Obrót
Forma obrotu         :Wolny rynek
Strona sprzedająca   :Osoba fizyczna
Strona kupująca      :Osoba fizyczna
Wartość              :334 650.00 zł

     Nieruchomość              :niezabudowana  przeznaczona pod zabudowę inną niż 
                                zagrodowa
     Księga wieczysta          :WA1L/00022800/1
     Obręb                     :8 - RAJSZEW
     Nr zmiany                 :42/2014
     Działki :                 
         Numer                 :9/18
         Powierzchnia          :2231 ( LzVI 1402 RVI 829)
         Funkcja dominująca    :Tereny zabudowy usługowej
         Rodzaj prawa          :Własność
         Udział w prawie       :1/1
====================================================================== : 
Dokument             :AN.A-4778/2014 z dnia 2014.03.03
IRCW                 :3705
Opis                 :DEZ 1352/2014
Rodzaj zapisu        :Obrót
Forma obrotu         :Wolny rynek
Strona sprzedająca   :Osoba fizyczna
Strona kupująca      :Osoba fizyczna
Wartość              :235 000.00 zł

     Nieruchomość              :lokalowa
     Księga wieczysta          :WA1L/00035911/6
     Obręb                     :1 - JABŁONNA
     Nr zmiany                 :767/2014
     Działki :                 
         Numer                 :2273
         Powierzchnia          :2187 ( B 2187)
         Funkcja dominująca    :brak danych
         Rodzaj prawa          :Własność
         Udział w prawie       :1/1
     Budynki :                 
         Numer                 :2273;1
         Funkcja podstawowa    :Mieszkalne
         Rok zak. budowy       :2002
         Pow. użytkowa         :2435
         Pow. zabudowy         :1242
         Liczba kond.          :3
         Liczba lokali         :45
         Rodzaj prawa          :Własność
         Udział w prawie       :1/1
         adres(y)              :JABŁONNA; LEŚNA 17b
     Lokale :                  
         Numer                 :2273;1,14
         Funkcja podstawowa    :Mieszkalne
         Liczba izb            :3
         Kondygnacja           :1
         Powierzchnia użytkowa :50.23    
         Rodzaj prawa          :Własność
         Udział w prawie       :1/1
         adres(y)              :JABŁONNA; LEŚNA 17b
====================================================================== : 
Dokument             :AN.A-5028/2014 z dnia 2014.05.05
IRCW                 :3704
Opis                 :DEZ 1348/2014
Rodzaj zapisu        :Obrót
Forma obrotu         :Wolny rynek
Strona sprzedająca   :Osoba fizyczna
Strona kupująca      :Osoba fizyczna
Wartość              :220 000.00 zł

     Nieruchomość              :niezabudowana  przeznaczona pod zabudowę inną niż 
                                zagrodowa
     Księga wieczysta          :WA1L/00044622/9
     Obręb                     :1 - JABŁONNA
     Nr zmiany                 :765/2014
     Działki :                 
         Numer                 :2759
         Powierzchnia          :1283 ( RIVb 1283)
         Funkcja dominująca    :Tereny zabudowy usługowej
         Rodzaj prawa          :Współwłasność
         Udział w prawie       :1/2
         Numer                 :54/25
         Powierzchnia          :1909 ( RIVb 540 RV 1369)
         Funkcja dominująca    :brak danych
         Rodzaj prawa          :Własność
         Udział w prawie       :1/1
         Numer                 :54/26
         Powierzchnia          :2994 ( RV 1318 RIVb 1676)
         Funkcja dominująca    :brak danych
         Rodzaj prawa          :Własność
         Udział w prawie       :1/1
====================================================================== :
```

Comment: You have newlines in your array. Try `.chomp` on each prior to storing. Or use `.map(&:chomp).join(",")` instead of just the `join(",")`.

Comment: Each line still has its newline at the end, e.g., if you run `in_file.each { |l| puts l.length }` you'll see the extra character.

Comment: The comments solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @MarkThomas pointed out `.map(&:chomp).join(',')` will clean up the new line characters but you could also use `readlines("\n")` and you code could be cleaned up a bit maybe something like this:(although even this code be refactored down more)

```
def pad_the_line(padding)
  @the_line.concat([''] * padding) 
end
def append_to_output
  @out_file << @the_line.map(&:chomp).join(",")
end
def set_padding(line)
  if line =~ /:\d+\/*\d*$/
    13
  elsif line=~/:\d+\/*\d*;\d+$/
    19
  elsif line=~/:\d+\/*\d*;\d+,\d+$/
    30
  else
    0
  end
end
def process_file(in_file='files/in.txt',out_file='files/out.csv')
  @out_file = File.open(out_file, 'w')
  first_plot = true
  @the_line = []
  File.open(in_file).readlines("\n").each_with_index do |line,index| 
    #the ===== line suggests it's time to save the line and start filling the second one. This is were I have problems somehow
    if line =~ /=+/
      append_to_output
      @the_line.clear
      first_plot = true
    #This is because every transaction can have several plots and I have to start new line as well. I know this needs refractoring. 
    elsif line=~ /Numer/
      if !(first_plot)
        append_to_output
        pad_the_line(set_padding(line))
      else 
      #this is the first time the plot is seen so we can have it in one line with transaction details
        first_plot = false
        m = /:(\S.*)$/.match(line)
        @the_line << $1
      end
    #This is for every normal value
    elsif line=~/:(\S.*)$/
      @the_line << $1
    else
      #you could also raise if needed
      warn "WARNING:: #{index + 1}: Error: #{line}" unless line =~ /[a-zA-Z]+ :\s+$/
    end
  end
  @out_file.close
end
```

Note when I run this against your file I get the following out put

```
WARNING:: 9: Error:

WARNING:: 11: Error:                                 zagrodowa

WARNING:: 30: Error:

WARNING:: 70: Error:

WARNING:: 72: Error:                                 zagrodowa
```

and an output file like this

```
AN.A-1437/2014 z dnia 2014.04.03,3706,DEZ 1380/2014,Obrót,Wolny rynek,Osoba fizyczna,Osoba fizyczna,334 650.00 zł,niezabudowana  przeznaczona pod zabudowę inną niż ,WA1L/00022800/1,8 - RAJSZEW,42/2014,9/18,2231 ( LzVI 1402 RVI 829),Tereny zabudowy usługowej,Własność,1/1AN.A-4778/2014 z dnia 2014.03.03,3705,DEZ 1352/2014,Obrót,Wolny rynek,Osoba fizyczna,Osoba fizyczna,235 000.00 zł,lokalowa,WA1L/00035911/6,1 - JABŁONNA,767/2014,2273,2187 ( B 2187),brak danych,Własność,1/1AN.A-4778/2014 z dnia 2014.03.03,3705,DEZ 1352/2014,Obrót,Wolny rynek,Osoba fizyczna,Osoba fizyczna,235 000.00 zł,lokalowa,WA1L/00035911/6,1 - JABŁONNA,767/2014,2273,2187 ( B 2187),brak danych,Własność,1/1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Mieszkalne,2002,2435,1242,3,45,Własność,1/1,JABŁONNA; LEŚNA 17bAN.A-4778/2014 z dnia 2014.03.03,3705,DEZ 1352/2014,Obrót,Wolny rynek,Osoba fizyczna,Osoba fizyczna,235 000.00 zł,lokalowa,WA1L/00035911/6,1 - JABŁONNA,767/2014,2273,2187 ( B 2187),brak danych,Własność,1/1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Mieszkalne,2002,2435,1242,3,45,Własność,1/1,JABŁONNA; LEŚNA 17b,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Mieszkalne,3,1,50.23    ,Własność,1/1,JABŁONNA; LEŚNA 17bAN.A-5028/2014 z dnia 2014.05.05,3704,DEZ 1348/2014,Obrót,Wolny rynek,Osoba fizyczna,Osoba fizyczna,220 000.00 zł,niezabudowana  przeznaczona pod zabudowę inną niż ,WA1L/00044622/9,1 - JABŁONNA,765/2014,2759,1283 ( RIVb 1283),Tereny zabudowy usługowej,Współwłasność,1/2AN.A-5028/2014 z dnia 2014.05.05,3704,DEZ 1348/2014,Obrót,Wolny rynek,Osoba fizyczna,Osoba fizyczna,220 000.00 zł,niezabudowana  przeznaczona pod zabudowę inną niż ,WA1L/00044622/9,1 - JABŁONNA,765/2014,2759,1283 ( RIVb 1283),Tereny zabudowy usługowej,Współwłasność,1/2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1909 ( RIVb 540 RV 1369),brak danych,Własność,1/1AN.A-5028/2014 z dnia 2014.05.05,3704,DEZ 1348/2014,Obrót,Wolny rynek,Osoba fizyczna,Osoba fizyczna,220 000.00 zł,niezabudowana  przeznaczona pod zabudowę inną niż ,WA1L/00044622/9,1 - JABŁONNA,765/2014,2759,1283 ( RIVb 1283),Tereny zabudowy usługowej,Współwłasność,1/2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1909 ( RIVb 540 RV 1369),brak danych,Własność,1/1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2994 ( RV 1318 RIVb 1676),brak danych,Własność,1/1
```